# codeigniter routed segments incorrectly converting dashes to underscores with nginx

Tags: codeigniter

I have a strange codeigniter 2 problem that I'm experiencing on a server running nginx 1.3.8. Dashes in my uri segments are being routed to my controller methods as underscores:

URL: http://myserver.com/dothis/some-slug-with-dashes/someid

In routes.php:

```
$route['^dothis/(.+)/(.+)$'] = "mycontroller/dothis/$1/$2";
```

In mycontroller.php

```
function dothis($slug, $id) {
  // echo $slug shows a value of "some_slug_with_dashes"
}
```

The same code on an apache webserver works as expected (the dashes remain dashes).

I did some tracing and debugging, and found the problem to be occurring around the _parse_routes() and _set_segments() functions of core/Router.php. On line 389 of Router.php is

```
return $this->_set_request(explode('/', $val));
```

Echoing the value of $val here shows that it is `/mycontroller/dothis/some-slug-with-dashes/F3e`.

Outputting the value of the explode() shows

```
Array
(
    [0] => mycontroller
    [1] => dothis
    [2] => some-slug-with-dashes
    [3] => someid
)
```

Tracing the execution to _set_request(), and if I insert a line to output the value of the `$segments` param:

```
function _set_request($segments = array())
{
    echo "\n<br/>_set_request() segments: <pre>";print_r($segments);echo "</pre>"; // inserted debug
    $segments = $this->_validate_request($segments);
    ...
}
```

what I get as the debug output is

```
_set_request() segments:

Array
(
    [0] => mycontroller
    [1] => dothis
    [2] => some_slug_with_dashes
    [3] => someid
)
```

If I echo additional debug output for `$this->uri->segments` and `$this->uri->rsegments` I get this:

```
// $this->uri->segments
Array
(
    [0] => dothis
    [1] => some-slug-with-dashes
    [2] => someid
)

// $this->uri->rsegments
Array
(
    [0] => mycontroller
    [1] => dothis
    [2] => some_slug_with_dashes
    [3] => someid
)
```

I've checked my codeigniter uri permitted chars, and it's the default settings. I've also checked nginx and fastcgi params, and they are the basic rules. I've also scoured the stackoverflow questions, and the nginx forums. It seems strange that php shows the correct value before the call to `_set_request()` but the modified value in the `_set_request() param`.

Does anyone know or have some suggested ideas on what could be causing this to happen?

UPDATE - my nginx configs are as follows:

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  35;

    # limit num of requests from single IP to 5req/s
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=flood:10m rate=5r/s;

    ##########################################################

    # load gzip settings
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf;

    # load geoip
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/geoip.conf;

    ##########################################################

    # load all vhosts
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

php.conf:

```
location ~ \.php {
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass   php;

    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;

    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

    ### SET GEOIP Variables ###
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE    $geoip_country_code;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3   $geoip_country_code3;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME    $geoip_country_name;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE   $geoip_city_country_code;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE3  $geoip_city_country_code3;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_NAME   $geoip_city_country_name;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_REGION              $geoip_region;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY                $geoip_city;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE         $geoip_postal_code;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_CONTINENT_CODE $geoip_city_continent_code;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_LATITUDE            $geoip_latitude;
    fastcgi_param GEOIP_LONGITUDE           $geoip_longitude;
}
```

my virtual host conf:

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:8004;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  myserver.com;
    return       301 http://www.myserver.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_tokens off;
    listen 80;
    server_name www.myserver.com;

    root /var/www/sites/com.mysite/httpdocs;
    access_log /var/www/sites/com.mysite/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/sites/com.mysite/logs/error.log;

    index index.html index.php;

       location /test {
                auth_basic "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file /var/www/sites/com.mysite/.htpasswd;
       }

    location / { 
        # if you're just using wordpress and don't want extra rewrites
        # then replace the word @rewrites with /index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }

    location @rewrites {
        # Can put some of your own rewrite rules in here
        # for example rewrite ^/~(.*)/(.*)/? /users/$1/$2 last;
        # If nothing matches we'll just send it to /index.php
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    # This block will catch static file requests, such as images, css, js
    # The ?: prefix is a 'non-capturing' mark, meaning we do not require
    # the pattern to be captured into $1 which should help improve performance
    #location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|txt|xml)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|txt|xml)$ {
        # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/drop.conf;
}
```

Comment: i dont think codeigniter likes dashes in urls. Best to steer clear from it.

Comment: @He Hui That is simply not true. Jay, you will need to provide more information as to your php-fpm and nginx configs, as it is hard to determine the cause. Also, have you tried nginx 1.2.6? 1.3.x is not currently the stable version.

Comment: HeHui codeigniter works just fine with dashes if they're rewritten. i've been running dashes w/o problems for years on apache. this is my first nginx install, and i seem to have gotten stuck on this issue. @brendan, nginx configs have been added.

Comment: Configs look fine... is it possible for you to try the stable branch of nginx? If 1.2.6 works, it may be a bug in 1.3.x that needs resolving.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem - developer error! Turned out a deploy script was not properly deleting an old errant MY_Router.php file from the nginx server (this file did not exist locally nor on the apache installs). Sorry for the false alarm - codeigniter, nginx, and php-fpm are working as expected. Developer (me) was not in this case.